# How do I change timer alarm tone in Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge +?

Tags: updates, clock, menu, samsung-galaxy-mega-2, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I upgraded from Galaxy Mega to Galaxy S6 Edge +.

There is no menu button. In Galaxy Mega, part of the menu contains changing the timer alarm tone.

How do I do that in S6 Edge +?

---

Galaxy mega has option in timer to change tone. This does not seem to be allowed in s6e+

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks but seriously? I have to download an app just for something that simple that was even in an old model? :|

Comment: There may be a way- I can't comment since I don't own the device. Hence offered a universal solution. But then, automation is not preferred by many, hence clarified before answering :)